# How to control primary key creation in lb4 discover

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

How can I control id (primary key) creation in `lb4 discover` ?

Whenever I call `lb4 discover` it sets `required: true` and `id: number` so I've to modify them manually into `required: false` and `id?: number` for all available primary keys which is very annoying thing (I've a huge database)

A tiny example of this issue:

```
CREATE TABLE public.lists (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    title varchar NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
    color int2 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT lists_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`lb4 discover` generates:

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';@model({
  settings: {
    idInjection: false,
    postgresql: {schema: 'public', table: 'lists'},
  },
})
export class Lists extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    //required: true, //------------------- A STUPID PROPERTY
    scale: 0,
    id: 1,
    postgresql: {
      columnName: 'id',
      dataType: 'integer',
      dataLength: null,
      dataPrecision: null,
      dataScale: 0,
      nullable: 'NO',
    },
  })
  id?: number;
  //id: number; //--------------------- A STUPID PROPERTY  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    postgresql: {
      columnName: 'title',
      dataType: 'character varying',
      dataLength: null,
      dataPrecision: null,
      dataScale: null,
      nullable: 'NO',
    },
  })
  title: string;  @property({
    type: 'string',
    postgresql: {
      columnName: 'description',
      dataType: 'text',
      dataLength: null,
      dataPrecision: null,
      dataScale: null,
      nullable: 'YES',
    },
  })
  description?: string;  @property({
    type: 'number',
    scale: 0,
    postgresql: {
      columnName: 'color',
      dataType: 'smallint',
      dataLength: null,
      dataPrecision: null,
      dataScale: 0,
      nullable: 'YES',
    },
  })
  color?: number;  // Define well-known properties here  // Indexer property to allow additional data
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [prop: string]: any;  constructor(data?: Partial<Lists>) {
    super(data);
  }
}export interface ListsRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}export type ListsWithRelations = Lists & ListsRelations;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in `lb4 discover` as mentioned right [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4557)